# Querying terms with calculations based on term meta data, sql vs. get_terms

Tags: meta-query, sql, meta-value

Is it viable and or advisable to try and implement a query like the below through get_terms and its meta query functionality?
Basically, I query terms of a specific taxonomy 'pr' that have meta fields containing coordinates based on distance from a reference coordinate.
My gut sense is that it will be more ellegant and efficient to keep the little pathagoras calaculation in the db query rather than having to loop through unnecessary results in php, perhaps I'm mistaken about that? Any pointers on what the structure of the meta querie(s?) should look like?

```
SET @refLat = -26.080;
SET @refLng = 28.015;
SELECT
    term.term_id,
    agt_Name.meta_value AS agt_Name,
    metaLat.meta_value AS metaLat,
    metaLng.meta_value AS metaLng,
    (
        SQRT(
            POW( @refLat - metaLat.meta_value, 2 ) + POW( @refLng - metaLng.meta_value, 2 )
        )
    ) * 111139 AS metresDistance
FROM
    `wp_terms` term
INNER JOIN `wp_term_taxonomy` tax ON
    ( term.term_id = tax.term_id AND tax.taxonomy = 'pr' )
INNER JOIN `wp_termmeta` metaLat ON
    ( term.term_id = metaLat.term_id AND metaLat.meta_key = '_latitude' )
INNER JOIN `wp_termmeta` metaLng ON
    ( term.term_id = metaLng.term_id AND metaLng.meta_key = '_longitude' )
INNER JOIN `wp_termmeta` agt_Name ON
    ( term.term_id = agt_Name.term_id AND agt_Name.meta_key = 'agt_Name' )
ORDER BY
    (
        SQRT(
            POW( @refLat - metaLat.meta_value, 2 ) + POW( @refLng - metaLng.meta_value, 2 )
        )
    ) ASC
    LIMIT 0,5
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This type of query is going to be extremely slow, and **ultra expensive**, and will scale extremely poorly with traffic. You should never find things based on what their post meta holds, especially if you're trying to do a calculation. Remember, for this type of query the DB will copy the entire term table 1 row at a time, performing the calculation on a full table scan, then perform the final queries on that new temporary table. This means as the number of terms and term meta increases, the time/resources needed for this query increase dramatically. I'd advise storing the data a different way

Comment: the only other way of storing the data I can think of, would be to have a completely separate custom db table with columns for the coordinate values and a term_taxonomyt_id to integrate with WordPress, unless I'm missing something else?

Comment: A table would be faster, but it's difficult too advise without knowing what a `pr` is, it could be that a taxonomy isn't the appropriate choice, or that there's a tradeoff you've made that both of us are unaware of ( usually it's extreme precision at the cost of performance ). Also keep in mind that the earth is not a flat grid, calculating distance with pythagorean equations will become less accurate as you get further north and south, and most of the world is surprisingly further north than people realise

Comment: Thanks for replying. In this case pr represents a real estate property. ( a taxonomy term rather than a custom post type to easily contain other post types like appointments, messages, offers etc.) 

Ultimately I have Xamarin based apps interacting via REST with the WordPress site. The site forms a kind of central hub and want to run a query like this because for example; I want to check if the mobile app being used by a property agent is withing some proximity to a pr/property, in which case there will be a check-in custom post created also associated with the pr term.

Comment: PS. I use the haversine formula elsewhere but wanted to keep the code simple in asking the question.

Comment: hmmm so a `pr` term might be something like `venice` with properties in that term being within a catchment area defined around a GPS location in the term meta? Keep in mind that if you went with a custom table, you wouldn't need to store all the data, just the term ID, latitude, and the longitude, then you could tell the database it's geolocation data and let the database optimise accordingly and save yourself having to re-implement the entire system

Comment: Belated thanks, your comments are very helpful and set me off in a slightly different direction.